# Why is this r code so slow?

Tags: performance, r, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe based on information in another dataframe.

the first dataframe (base_mar_bop) has data like:

```
201301|ABC|4
201302|DEF|12
```

my wish is to create a data frame from this with 16 rows in it:

```
4 times: 201301|ABC|1
12 times: 201302|DEF|1
```

I have written a script that takes ages to run. To get an idea the final dataframe has around 2 million rows and the source dataframe has about 10k rows. I can not post sourcefiles for the dataframes due to confidentiality of the data.

Since it took ages to run this code, I decided to do this in PHP and it ran in under a minute and got the job done, writing it to a txt file and then importing the txt file in R.

I have no clue why R takes so long.. Is it the calling of the function? Is it the nested for loop? From my point of view there are not that many computationally intensive steps in there.

```
# first create an empty dataframe called base_eop that will each subscriber on a row 

identified by CED, RATEPLAN and 1
# where 1 is the count and the sum of 1 should end up with the base
base_eop <-base_mar_bop[1,]

# let's give some logical names to the columns in the df
names(base_eop) <- c('CED','RATEPLAN','BASE')


# define the function that enables us to insert a row at the bottom of the dataframe
insertRow <- function(existingDF, newrow, r) {
  existingDF[seq(r+1,nrow(existingDF)+1),] <- existingDF[seq(r,nrow(existingDF)),]
  existingDF[r,] <- newrow
  existingDF
}


# now loop through the eop base for march, each row contains the ced, rateplan and number of subs
# we need to insert a row for each individual sub
for (i in 1:nrow(base_mar_eop)) {
  # we go through every row in the dataframe
  for (j in 1:base_mar_eop[i,3]) {
    # we insert a row for each CED, rateplan combination and set the base value to 1
    base_eop <- insertRow(base_eop,c(base_mar_eop[i,1:2],1),nrow(base_eop)) 
  }
}

# since the dataframe was created using the first row of base_mar_bop we need to remove this first row
base_eop <- base_eop[-1,]
```

Comment: you'll be much better off defining the whole data frame in advance and then filling it in rather than appending rows.  I think this is discussed in Pat Burns's "R Inferno".  Also consider using the `data.table` package for large manipulations like this.

Comment: provide a small (tiny really, smth you can put in the code above) reproducible example dataset

Comment: should the second line in your output example be `201302|DEF|1` (i.e 1 rather than 12 in the last place) ?

Comment: @BenBolker updated the line to have |1 at the end.. tnx

Comment: by the way, you could easily put together a reproducible example with arbitrary data, e.g. `data.frame(CED=1:10000,RATEPLAN=rep(LETTERS[1:25],length.out=10000),BASE=2000)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach with `data.table`, though @BenBolker's timings are already awesome.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(d2)  ## d2 from @BenBolker's answer
out <- DT[, ID:=1:.N][rep(ID, BASE)][, `:=`(BASE=1, ID=NULL)]
out
#            CED RATEPLAN BASE
#       1:     1        A    1
#       2:     1        A    1
#       3:     1        A    1
#       4:     1        A    1
#       5:     1        A    1
#      ---                    
# 1999996: 10000        Y    1
# 1999997: 10000        Y    1
# 1999998: 10000        Y    1
# 1999999: 10000        Y    1
# 2000000: 10000        Y    1
```

Here, I've used compound queries to do the following:

- Create an ID variable that is really just 1 to the number of rows in the `data.table`.
- Use `rep` to repeat the ID variable by the corresponding BASE value.
- Replaced all BASE values with "1" and dropped the ID variable we created earlier.

Perhaps there is a more efficient way to do this though. For example, dropping one of the compound queries should make it a little faster. Perhaps something like:

```
out <- DT[rep(1:nrow(DT), BASE)][, BASE:=1]
```

Comment: another way to skin the cat that seems slightly faster: `DT[DT[, rep(.I, BASE)]][, BASE:=1]`

Comment: +1 my motivation for seeing a data.table solution wasn't speed, but trying to understand how the syntax works. Bens method is more immediately intuitive to me but compound queries seem *so* powerful, if only I could *get it* !

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried any benchmarking yet, but this approach (illustrated on your mini-example) should be *much* faster:

```
d <- data.frame(x1=c(201301,201302),x2=c("ABC","DEF"),rep=c(4,12))
with(d,data.frame(x1=rep(x1,rep),x2=rep(x2,rep),rep=1))
```

A slightly more realistic example, with timing:

```
d2 <- data.frame(CED=1:10000,RATEPLAN=rep(LETTERS[1:25],
         length.out=10000),BASE=200) 
nrow(d2) ## 10000
sum(d2$BASE)  ## 2e+06
system.time(d3 <- with(d2,
      data.frame(CED=rep(CED,BASE),RATEPLAN=rep(RATEPLAN,BASE),
              BASE=1)))
##   user  system elapsed 
## 0.244   0.860   1.117 
nrow(d3)  ## 2000000 (== 2e+06)
```

Comment: +1 but I'd love to see a data.table solution here from someone. I still can't get my head around the syntax

Comment: +1. Awesome speed improvement. @SimonO101, I'm not sure whether `data.table` would necessarily be faster than Ben's approach here. They aren't with my attempt at an answer, but I might not be using `data.table` very effectively either. But, the syntax is a *lot* more compact, and when you're talking about whether you have to wait  100 milliseconds more or less, then I think the discussions about speed are somewhat silly :)